# Python : Separating the terms in a list and assigning values

Tags: python

I have used a keyword extractor and obtained a list as given below-

```
[('solutions design team', 0.5027793039863974), 
('communication skills', 0.039048703166463736), 
('internal stakeholders', 0.03230578820017667),
('potential customers', 0.020380881551651655), ('utilize', 0.002776174060064261)]
```

I'm trying to separate each of these words and assign the corresponding value(given on the right) to each of them respectively.

For eg- Make 'solutions design team' = 0.5027793039863974 into

```
'solutions' = 0.5027793039863974, 
'design' = 0.5027793039863974 ,   
'team' = 0.5027793039863974.
```

Comment: What `solutions=` if `[('solutions design team', 0.5027793039863974), 
('solutions skills', 0.039048703166463736)]`

Comment: What is your desired output? A list of tuples or dictionary?

Comment: @lagon thats alright the next 'solutions' tag that appears should take the 0.039048703166463736 value

Comment: @jpp The output is - 
'solutions' = 0.5027793039863974, 
'design' = 0.5027793039863974 ,   
'team' = 0.5027793039863974.

Comment: @SalazarSid, That's not a valid Python object. Type that in your favourite IDE and it will fail with `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @jpp Apologies, The output i expect is just as Jean-Francois Fabre has provided below, i.e
[('solutions', 0.5027793039863974),
 ('design', 0.5027793039863974),
 ('team', 0.5027793039863974),
 ('communication', 0.039048703166463736),
 ('skills', 0.039048703166463736),
 ('internal', 0.03230578820017667),
 ('stakeholders', 0.03230578820017667),
 ('potential', 0.020380881551651655),
 ('customers', 0.020380881551651655),
 ('utilize', 0.002776174060064261)]

Comment: @SalazarSid, See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52735598/python-separating-the-terms-in-a-list-and-assigning-values?noredirect=1#comment92396567_52735645).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using double flat comprehension to re-create a list of tuples with separated words:

```
inlist = [('solutions design team', 0.5027793039863974),
('communication skills', 0.039048703166463736),
('internal stakeholders', 0.03230578820017667),
('potential customers', 0.020380881551651655), ('utilize', 0.002776174060064261)]

outlist = [(word,value) for words,value in inlist for word in words.split()]
```

result:

```
>>> outlist
[('solutions', 0.5027793039863974),
 ('design', 0.5027793039863974),
 ('team', 0.5027793039863974),
 ('communication', 0.039048703166463736),
 ('skills', 0.039048703166463736),
 ('internal', 0.03230578820017667),
 ('stakeholders', 0.03230578820017667),
 ('potential', 0.020380881551651655),
 ('customers', 0.020380881551651655),
 ('utilize', 0.002776174060064261)]
```

note that if the keywords are present more than once, you'll have duplicates in the list of tuples. If you want to accumulate them, a `collections.defaultdict(float)` object could be handy to create a dictionary with keywords=>accumulated values.

```
accumulated = collections.defaultdict(float)
for word,value in outlist:
    accumulated[word] += value
```

Comment: This output is exactly what i was looking for thanks!
I plan to add the scores of the repeated keywords so it suits me just fine.

Comment: @SalazarSid, There are 2 different solutions here. Which one suits you? Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52735598/edit) to make it clear so we don't have a disjointed Q&A? `I plan to add the scores of the repeated keywords` isn't straightforward with the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

Dict comprehensions, dict update may help you in the way below

```
corpus = [('solutions design team', 0.5027793039863974), ('communication skills', 0.039048703166463736), ('internal stakeholders', 0.03230578820017667), ('potential customers', 0.020380881551651655), ('utilize', 0.002776174060064261)]

final_dict = {}
for phase, prob in corpus:
    final_dict.update({word:prob for word in phase.split()}

print(final_dict['solutions'])
print(final_dict['design'])
```